# SharePoint Online new aspx files keep downloading instead of showing

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created a document library, and put my aspx files into it. The files are working fine till last Friday.

From last Friday, after I made changes and re-attached the file, instead of opening the file from browser, it downloads the file when clicking on it. And if I copied the URL and pasted it into the address box, it says "Sorry, something went wrong. File was not found".

Answer (score 0):

Whether the aspx files are SharePoint pages? Per my test, after download, edit the aspx file and reupload the file, the aspx file is broken.

If we want to customize a SharePoint page, we can use using SharePoint Designer to achieve it.

Open SharePoint site in SharePoint Designer, click All Files in the left panel, click relevant document library and aspx file, right click Edit file in Advanced mode.

Answer (score 0):

Disable parameter setting "DenyAddAndCustomizePages".

Here's the PowerShell code to do so:

```
Set-SPOsite https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/teamxyz -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Then upload the .ASPX file as Site Owner to the document library. It won't work if you just have "Member" permissions to the site.